# Render JPEG 2000 Image Compression Dicom with Fo-Dicom

Tags: c#, .net, fo-dicom

I'm try to create a simple WinForms viewer to show DICOM files generated in a NOVARAD PACS system. I'm using the following code from their [GitHub page](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom):

```
var image = new DicomImage(@"C:\myDicom.dcm");                        
image.RenderImage().AsClonedBitmap().Save(@"test.jpg");
Process.Start("test.jpg");
```

When I run this code I get the following error:

> Dicom.Imaging.Codec.DicomCodecException: 'Decoding dataset with
> transfer syntax: JPEG 2000 Image Compression (Lossless Only) is not
> supported.'

I'm assuming I need to decompress from the JPEG 2000. Can this not be done with fo-dicom?

I was trying to play around with GDCM library but I couldn't find the C# wrapper, and noticed several comments saying they rolled it into fo-dicom.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you set the build architecture for your application to x86 or x64? On .NET Framework, Any CPU architecture won't work.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson WOW yeah that did the trick !  Thank you so much.  If you put that as an answer I will gladly mark it.  Been struggling to figure that out for two days

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Can you point me in the direction of opening multi image DICOM MRI files ?

Comment: I suppose you mean multiframe images? There should be examples of how to do that at least in the *DICOM.Dump* application. You might also have a look at the *fo-dicom-samples* Github repository where there might be more examples.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson Thanks Anders I'll check it out.  Never realized how complex DICOMs were.  Very interesting learning curve.  Thank you for your project !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET Framework applications, the build architecture needs to be set to x86 or x64. Codec access on *Any CPU* architecture will not work, since there are no native codec libraries available for that architecture. For more information, see the *fo-dicom* [wiki](https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki/Native-codecs-on-.NET).