# Decoding dataset with transfer syntax: JPEG 2000 Image Compression is not supported

Tags: c#, wpf, fo-dicom

I know this problem already handled below link

[Render JPEG 2000 Image Compression Dicom with Fo-Dicom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52542678/render-jpeg-2000-image-compression-dicom-with-fo-dicom)

However, to change building x86 or x64 from Any CPU, didn't work to my problem.

it seems exactly same problem at above link, because my troubling part looks same as above:

`WriteableBitmap bmp = image.RenderImage().As<WriteableBitmap>();`

I'm using vs2019 and referencing fo-dicom 4.0.3
Thanks for any help!

Comment: What framework are you targetting? (e.g. net461, netcoreapp2.2 etc) Have you got a reference to `<PackageReference Include="fo-dicom.Drawing" Version="4.0.3" />`

Comment: @ThomasN I'm targeting NetcoreApp 3.0 and for second question, yes I checked fo-dicom.Drawing is registered for package

Answer (score 3):

First of all take a look at this wiki-page: https://github.com/fo-dicom/fo-dicom/wiki/Supported-Transfer-Syntaxes
Depending on the platform you are building, not all transfer syntaxes are supported.

If you are building for desktop, then you have to build explicit in x86 or x64, not in AnyCpu. Thats because the native codecs have to be linked on building and there fo-dicom needs to know which of the native dlls to link.

if you are building netcore, fo-dicom does not support that many codecs out of the box. Then take a look at https://github.com/Efferent-Health/Dicom-native. They shared their codec that runs on every netcore platform.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and info. I think I chose a wrong platform.. I will check it.

Comment: Is the table in the link still valid now with fo 5.X ? 
Or don't we have a"Desktop" lib anymore and will get anyways "Jpeg 2000 not supported? (as I do currently after switching from .NET 4.8 x64 Fo-4.x -> .NET 4.8 Fo-5.X x64)

Comment: no, the table is only for version 4. From version 5 von, fo-dicom does not deliver codecs out of the box, but they are maintained by Efferent-Health, as described on the main read.me of github/fo-dicom/fo-dicom. There all those transfersyntaxes are supported on windows, linux and mac.